# How to start an android service without application first run?

Tags: android, service

I am new on android. I have an android application. It has a service should run after device startup/reboot/boot. But the service does not start without the user starts application ones. After first running of application, the service starts correctly on every reboot/startup/boot.

I want that the service starts without need to the application first run.So, what is the reason of this? And how can i do it?

Here is service registering in manifest file of application:

```
        <receiver android:name="com.example.ota_file.StartUpBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Here is the service code :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StartUpBootReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            //TO DO
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> in your manifest?

Comment: See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html) and [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html) from July 2011, when this was introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a security change Google made back in the 2.x days.  Unless an activity from the app has run at least once, no broadcast receivers will run, including BOOT_COMPLETE.  There is no way around it, the app must have an activity run at least once to be removed from the force stopped state.

Comment: Actually, it was Android 3.1.

Comment: Ok. What about the system applications? This applicaiton will be system application.